HELP me solve this problem, I had been stuck with it for a while
Consider the function $f(x)=x\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}$, then find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{f(x)}$
BTW, the answer is 3/4, can't figure it out...

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

$f(x)=x\sqrt{1+f(x+1)}$

$$f(x)=x\sqrt{1+(x+1)\sqrt{1+(x+2)\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}$$
$$x + n + a = \sqrt{ax + (n+a)^2 + x \sqrt{a(x+n) + (n+a)^2 + (x+n)

\sqrt{\dots}}}$$

Therefore,
$$f(x)=x^2+2x$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{f(x)}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x(x+2)}= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+2}\right]=\frac{3}{4}$$

$f(x)=x^2+2x$... I just saw in cafe.

It's easy to see that $f(x) = x\sqrt{1 + f(x+1)}$. Since the function is positive we can square both sides without worrying about the sign. Therefore we have to solve the functional equation: $[f(x)]^2 = x^2(1 + f(x+1))$. If we assume $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ then we know that the following must hold: $$\deg f^2 = \deg x^2(1+f(x+1)) \iff 2n = \max\{2, n+2\}$$
Which only holds when $n=2$. Therefore if $f$ is a polynomial it is of degree $2$, i.e. $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$. If we substitute this form of $f(x)$ into the original functional equation we get: $$(ax^2+bx+c)^2 = x^2(1+a(x+1)^2 + b(x+1) + c)$$
From here we can expand the polynomials on both sides and equate like coefficients. We obtain the following system for the coefficients:
$$\begin{cases}a^2 =a\newline 2ab = 2a + b\newline 2ac+b^2 = a + b + c\newline 2bc = 0\newline c^2 = 0\end{cases}$$
Therefore $f(x) = x^2 + 2x = x(x+2)$. Returning to the infinite series we get (I've changed the variable's names a little but it's the same thing otherwise): $$\begin{aligned}&\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac 1 {f(n)} = \\ &=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n(n+2)}=\\&=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N (\frac{1/2}{n} + \frac{-1/2}{n+2}) = \\&=\frac 1 2 \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N (\frac 1 n -\frac 1 {n+2}) = \frac 1 2 (1 + \frac 1 2) = \frac 3 4
\end{aligned}$$
Of course this all relies on the assumption that $f$ is a polynomial so it's not necessarily the only solution to the original functional equation however other (non-polynomial) solutions would probably be very very hard to find.
